# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi sala de chat php pueda el usuario crear una igual para sus uso

Tags: php

tengo una sala de chat en tiempo real funcionando todo excelente, pero qué pasos básicos debo seguir para que cada usuario pueda crear su propia sala donde los usuarios que ingresen puedan conversar

Probé usar videos para aprender pero sigo atorado, creo que estoy cerca pero no puedo

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).